# Validation post ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a column in my table 'plan_id' for when a user pays and subscribes. Braintree sends me back the plan that they subscribed to. Users are allowed to post more ads based on what subscription they pay for. What I have doesn't work :/. Maybe someone can give me a hand

```
def validates_posts!
        return if user.nil?
         if user.plan_id == 'nil' && user.posts.count > 2
            errors.add(:base, 'Cannot add more than 10 Ads at a time')
         elsif user.plan_id == 'Premium' && user.posts.count > 10
            errors.add(:base, 'Cannot add more than 10 Ads at a time')
         else user.plan_id == 'Business' && user.posts.count > 30
            errors.add(:base, 'Cannot add more than 30 Ads at a time')
         end
    end
```

Here is my schema and my user table

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "braintree_id"
    t.string "braintree_subscription_id"
    t.boolean "admin"
    t.string "user_type"
    t.string "business_name"
    t.string "business_phone"
    t.string "business_website"
    t.string "plan_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? give examples of the expected and the current behaviour. Is `'nil'` a valid value for plan_id? or should it be `nil` as `user.plan_id.nil?`?.

Comment: Remember that in Ruby only two things are logically false, `nil` and `false`. Every other value is considered truthful. That means tests like `if (!user.plan_id.nil?)` can be written as `if (user.plan_id)` since `false` is not a valid value. Rails also adds helper methods that test if the value is assigned and not empty/blank: `if (user.plan_id?)` does just that.

Comment: This could also be cleaned up considerably if you had the limit expressed in the plan, as you could do `if (user.posts.count > user.plan.post_limit)`. Expressing limits in code is bad, and it's especially bad if you're tying it to the English language label, something that's liable to change.

Comment: Are you getting some error? Or something is just “not happening”? Please explain further so we can help you.